# Partitioner implements StepExecutionListener but beforeStep is not called

Tags: java, spring-batch, partitioning

I have this job but when running it the beforeStep method in the partitioner is never called. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Configuration
public class SomeJob {

@Bean(name = "some-job")
public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get(getName())
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(stepOne())
            .next(stepTwo())
            .build();
}

private Step stepOne() {
    TaskletStep stepOne = stepBuilderFactory
            .get("step-one")
            .<...>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
            .reader(someReader())
            .writer(someWriter())
            .build();

    return stepBuilderFactory
            .get("partitionedStepOne")
            .partitioner(stepOne)
            .partitioner("partition", partitioner())
            .taskExecutor(someExecutor())
            .gridSize(SIZE)
            .build();
}


@Bean
@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
Partitioner partitioner() {
    return new OffsetBasedPartitioner(NAME, storedArticleMasterDataRepository);
}
} // end of job class
....

public class OffsetBasedPartitioner implements Partitioner, StepExecutionListener {

@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
  ...
}
...
}
```

I would avoid xml configuration files if possible.

Comment: I don't know JavaConfig well, but I suppose partitioner() is not automatically registered as listener but you have to register it manually

Comment: thanks @LucaBassoRicci , do you have any idea how to do that? are annotations enough or do I need xml config?

Comment: I suppose you can find a listener() method in StepBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @LucaBassoRicci for his suggestion, I added the partitioner as listener in the step definition:

```
return stepBuilderFactory
        .get("partitionedStepOne")
        .partitioner(stepOne)
        .partitioner("partition", partitioner())
        .listener(partitioner())
        .taskExecutor(someExecutor())
        .gridSize(SIZE)
        .build();
```

and left all the rest as above, now it works :)

Comment: Very nice workaround to register the same bean as a partitioner and listener.